# How can I read Exchange 2003 email on a Mac with Outlook 2011?

Tags: email, calendar, ms-office, exchange-activesync

I previously here asked about a [problem setting up Exchange server on Outlook 2011](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28095). The answer provided began, "Outlook 2011 requires an Exchange 2007 and above server."

Problem is - my company has Exchange 2003 and they're not likely to change any time soon.

How can I read my email on my Mac? And is there a way I can also fully use my calendar (including scheduling appointments with colleagues)?

*(My Mac's full technical specifications are in the linked question.)*

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2011 can also connect to POP and IMAP accounts, so if your Exchange implementation supports those (IMAP preferred over POP) you should be able to use OL.  Of course, that's not a 'true' Exchange client setup.

Likely better to use your company's Outlook Web Access (OWA), or acquire Entourage 2008.